# Returning multiple JSON from controller in Laravel

Tags: json, ajax, laravel

I have something like this in the route:

```
Route::post('/iteminfo/{item_id}','itemcontroller@get_item_info');
```

And something like this in the controller

```
public function get_item_info($request)
{
$item_image = Item_Image->where("item_id",$request)->first();
$item_something = Item_Something->where("item_id",$request)->first();
$item_more = Item_More->where("item_id",$request)->first();

return Response::json($item_image);

}
```

I want to return the 3 things but with return Response::json() I can only return 1 statement (as far as I know). Is there any way to return all of them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass an array as the json response. So craft an array based on your data and use it.

```
return Response::json(array(
    'item_image' => $item_image,
    'item_something' => $item_something,
    'item_more' => $item_more,
));
```

Comment: don't forget use Response; at the top

Answer (score 7):

Since it requires an `Array` parameter so you can construct an array from the variables

```
 return response()->json(['item_image ' => $item_image, 'item_something' => $item_something, 'item_more' => $item_more  ]);
```

Or

```
return Response::json(['item_image ' => $item_image, 'item_something' => $item_something, 'item_more' => $item_more  ]);
```

Comment: You forget the "p" letter. Must be return Response::json